# How can I tell selenium webserver standalone which firefox version to use?

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

Usually I start my selenium server like this:

java -jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.profile=MyProfile /usr/local/bin/selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar

My programming language is php, so I use mink in which I initialize the Selenium2Driver. By executin my phpunit tests everything works fine, my firefox is started and all the tests run as they should. But selenium always starts my installed firefox version.

How can I start a standalone version? Is there a parameter telling selenium which firefox to start? Or do I have tell mink which one I want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.firefox.bin="C:\WhateverFolder\youhaveFFON\firefox.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks, that's excactly the paramater I wanted!