# How to tell Webdriver to use a specific version of ChromeDriver?

Tags: selenium, command-line, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to run Selenium tests in a command line environment. I've reached a point where I'm facing with Chrome version mismatch. When I run the tests WebDriver downloads and uses ChromeDriver version 2.27 but I need 2.24. If I manually download it with the `selenium-standalone install` command then rename the downloaded file from `2.24` to `2.27` my tests start running.
Where can I update the WebDriver config to use a specific version of ChromeDriver? I guess it needs to tell to Selenium (`selenium-standalone`) somehow.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41769997/how-can-i-tell-selenium-webserver-standalone-which-firefox-version-to-use

Comment: I need to tell it through webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using npm, try using 
`selenium-standalone install --drivers.chrome.version=2.24` as mentioned [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-standalone)

Comment: That installs Chromedriver 2.27 but Webdriver would still use its default from config.

Comment: @haxpanel I have corrected the version number in the answer. You should update your config.json with the version number you want to use.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly to update? I can't find that key in the webdriver config.

Comment: You need to update chromedriver version in protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\config.json. Same as your chromedriver version.

Answer (score 1):

I have been hitting this dead end very often. Everytime New chromeDriver is released and my company administrator group policy wont allow me to upgrade Chromebrowser.

This puts me in soup, I have to corrupt WebDriverManager jar file to stop downloading latest version of ChromeDriver before running Selenium Scripts.

****SOLUTION:**** 
To Stop downloading latest version of ChromeDriver by WebDriverManager.jar for Selenium, use the below line before invoking chrome driver.

"WebDriverManager.chromedriver().version("2.42").setup();"

Also, dont use the below 
"ChromeDriverManager.getInstance().setup();" - this is the guy who downloads latest version of ChromeDriver every time when we run script.

100% this solution Works.